# Geometric interpretation for the row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a clear understanding of how the column space relates to a transformation of the basis vectors, but I really do not see the connection between the column space and the row space of the matrix.

If we have $3 \times 3$ transformation matrix $A$ defined by

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We have the basis for the column space given by

$$
\left( \vec{c_1}\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} \\
    a_{21} \\
    a_{31}
\end{pmatrix}, \vec{c_2}\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{12} \\
    a_{22} \\
    a_{32}
\end{pmatrix}, \vec{c_3}\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{13} \\
    a_{23} \\
    a_{33}
\end{pmatrix} \right)
$$

Then the operation on a $3 \times 1$ column vector $\vec{v}$ is defined as

$$
A \cdot \vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    xa_{11} + ya_{12} + za_{13} \\
    xa_{21} + ya_{22} + za_{23} \\
    xa_{31} + ya_{32} + za_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is equivalent to the linear combination of the basis vectors for the column space $\left( \vec{c_1}, \vec{c_2}, \vec{c_3} \right)$ such as

$$A \cdot \vec{v} = x\vec{c_1} + y\vec{c_2} + z\vec{c_3}$$

Or the dot product with the basis vectors for the row space as shown in the matrix-vector product. We have the basis for the row space given by

$$
\left( \vec{r_1}\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} \\
    a_{12} \\
    a_{13}
\end{pmatrix}, \vec{r_2}\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{21} \\
    a_{22} \\
    a_{23}
\end{pmatrix}, \vec{r_3}\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{31} \\
    a_{32} \\
    a_{33}
\end{pmatrix} \right)
$$

And the resulting matrix-vector product given by

$$
A \cdot \vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \vec{r_1} \cdot \vec{v} \\
    \vec{r_2} \cdot \vec{v} \\
    \vec{r_3} \cdot \vec{v}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My question concerns the relationship between the linear span of the column space and the linear span of the row space.

Is there any geometric relationship between the column space and the row space apart from this algebraic manipulation that emphasizes the fact the linear combination of the basis vectors for the column space $\left( \vec{c_1}, \vec{c_2}, \vec{c_3} \right)$ is equal to the projection onto the basis vectors for the row space $\left( \vec{r_1}, \vec{r_2}, \vec{r_3} \right)$?

I am looking for a more geometric interpretation rather than the standard algebraic relationship.

Comment: Keep in mind that for any subspaces $C,R \subset \Bbb R^3$ of the same dimension, we can find a linear transformation with column space $C$ and row space $R$.  In that sense, the only geometric relationship that the two spaces must have with each other is that they must be the same dimension.

Comment: More generally, the row space and kernel are subspaces of the transformation's domain, whereas the column space and cokernel are subspaces of the codomain.  Each pair of spaces is a set of orthogonal complements, but the only relationship we can guarantee between one of the domain spaces and one of the codomain spaces is that of dimension.

Comment: Of course if we put some restrictions on $A$ other than merely specifying its size (e.g. $A$ is symmetric or normal), then we can say a bit more here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yeah I see, but I was specifically talking about the dot product of the row vectors (projection onto the row space) relates to the linear combination of the column vectors (the basis of the column space)

Comment: There is no direct relationship between the projection onto the row space and "the" basis of the column space; such a relationship would be equivalent to a direct relationship between the row space and column space, which as I say above does not exist.

Comment: Also note that unless the column-space is all of $\Bbb R^3$, the columns will not form a basis of the column space.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but matrix-vector multiplication is the dot product of each row vector, and matrix-vector multiplication is also the linear combination of the columns vectors, I was specifically talking about this “relation”

Comment: Your question, as is currently phrased, asks whether your algebraic relationship between the rows of a matrix and its columns can be used to give us a geometric relationship between the column space and row space.  My answer to that question is no.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so this relation is simply nothing more than algebraic coincidence?

Comment: I am not saying that.  I am saying, however, that it can't be conveyed by looking only at the row space and column space in any way, let alone geometrically.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so what is the connection? Dual space as the transposed matrix multiplication? I just want to have a clear relationship apart from this algebraic coincidence (which is not a coincidence)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom this is rather interesting as the dot product refer to a projection, so the projection onto the subspace spanned by the row vectors gives the coordinates of the scalar multiplication by the column vectors. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One nice interpretation of this phenomenon comes out of studying the bilinear form $f:\Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x,y) = x^TAy$.

Note that for any fixed $x \in \Bbb R^3$, the function $f(x,\cdot): \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x,\cdot)(y) = f(x,y)$ gives us a linear map (an element of the dual space to $\Bbb R^3$, if you prefer). We can identify the column space of $A$ with all maps of the form $f(x,\cdot)$; each column of $A$ corresponds to plugging in a standard basis vector for $x$.  Similarly, we can identify the row space of $A$ with all maps of the form $f(\cdot,y)$; each row of $A$ corresponds to plugging in a standard basis vector for $y$.

In a sense, your observation amounts to the statement that 
$$
f(x, \cdot)(y) = f(\cdot,y)(x).
$$

Comment: So using column vectors as the basis for linear transformations is only a matter of convention then, we could use the row vectors as another basis and describe linear transformations using transposed vectors, the matrix is just a notation to package the information for that specific transformation. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and exchanging the roles of rows and columns for a given matrix gives us the transformation corresponding to the transpose. That being said, in order to get geometric meaning from a matrix, we choose one convention and stick to it.  I think that the best way to get some "meaning" out of your observation is to find an interpretation for what it is that $f(x,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot,y)$ "do".

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the dot product formula as shown in my post has actually no meaning if we are not in an orthonormal basis, if this is the case, then this is nothing but an addition of coefficients, the dot product is only defined this way. What do you think?